# GitHub maintain repo within repo directory

Tags: git, github, pull, git-pull, multiple-repositories

Im super new with using GitHub.. I cloned in a repo at html/mycms (repo is mycms) and now I have another repo I would like to maintain within.. I cloned it in at html/mycms/system/docs (repo is called docs).

BUT, not when I pull, I only get updates to html/mycms and the docs one is ignored? I assume this is because the folder html/mycms has already been set to the mycms repo? I don't know how to fix this issue though..

How can I pull the docs repo while it's within my mycms repo? And can I pull both at the same time somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use git submodules for what you want. The docs repo will have to be hosted separately (on Github) and you add it as a submodule to your main repo. That way, when you clone it as `git clone --recursive git@github.com:user/mainrepo`, you will get the submodule docs repo in as well.

Look here to know about submodules: http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html

Comment: Ok, I did see some stuff about that. Are there any draw backs to doing it this way? Would you recommend an alternative method? Thanks!

Comment: @RyanThompson - I don't see drawbacks for the scenario that you mention.